# g++ compiler flag to minimize binary size

Tags: c++, arduino, g++, compiler-optimization

I'm have an Arduino Uno R3. I'm making logical objects for each of my sensors using C++. The Arduino has very limited on-board memory 32KB*, and, on average, my compiled objects are coming out around 6KB*.

I am already using the smallest possible data types required, in an attempt to minimize my memory footprint. Is there a compiler flag to minimize the size of the binary, or do I need to use shorter variable and function names, less functions, etc. to minimize my code base?

Also, any other tips or words of advice for minimizing binary size would be appreciated.

*It may not be measured in KB (as I don't have it sitting in front of me), but 1 object is approximately 1/5 of my total memory size, which is prompting my concern.

Comment: gcc -o3 , -o2  O for optimize

Comment: @Grijesh No... -O3 will make binaries larger in general.

Comment: @Zak The gcc option that optimizes for size is `-Os`. You can also `strip` the symbols for your binaries after linking.

Comment: @us2012 Really! I thought `3` for better level what its for?

Comment: Are you using templates, from the standard library or your own inventions? These tend to introduce additional code for every type they're instantiated with. Function and variable name size has **no** effect whatsoever on binary size (if you strip debug info and such, which you should anyway).

Comment: variable names do not affect the size of generated machine code. but if you leave debugging information in the executable, remove that. the g++ option for that is `-s`. with only 32K to play around with I would seriously consider using hand-crafted assembly language rather than C++. just sayin'. ;-)

Comment: @Grijesh Execution speed and binary size do not necessarily correlate.  Things like loop unrolling and frequent inlining may make the program faster, but increase the size of the binaries...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There are lots of techniques to reduce binary size in addition to what `us2012` and others mentioned in the comments, summing them up with some points of my own:

- Use `-Os` to make gcc/g++ optimize for size.
- Use `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections` to separate each function or data into distinct sections within the translation unit. Combine it with the linker option `-Wl,--gc-sections` to get rid of any unreferenced sections.
- Run `strip` with at least the following options: `-s -R .comment -R .gnu.version`. It can be combined with `--strip-unneeded` to remove all symbols that are not necessary for relocation processing.

Answer (score 20):

If your code does not contain c++-exception-handling you can save a lot of space (up to 30k after all optimize steps mentioned by Tuxdude).
Therefore you have to provide the following flag:
`-fno-exceptions`

But **even** if  you **don't** use exceptions, the exception handling can be included!
Check the following steps:

1. `no usage of new, delete`. If you really need it replace them by malloc/free wrappers. For an example search for "tinynew.cpp"
2. provide function for pure virtual call, e.g.`extern "C" void __cxa_pure_virtual() { while(1); }`
3. overwrite __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler(). It handles unhandled exceptions and does name demangling, which is quite large! (e.g d_print_comp.part.10 with 9.5k or d_type with 1.8k)

Cheers 
Flo

Comment: Point 3 helped a lot! Thanks!