# Getting debug symbols in final SO file even when building Release in CMake

Tags: android, c++, gcc, android-ndk, g++

I'm using CMake (generator is ninja) to build a shared library using the NDK toolchain (g++ 4.9). Below is the verbose output for building a single CPP file in the library when I build with ninja:

> [34/164] /usr/local/bin/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++   -DANDROID -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -fexceptions -frtti -fpic -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/usr/local/bin/android-ndk/platforms/android-15/arch-arm -funwind-tables -finline-limit=64 -fsigned-char -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack  -mthumb -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -O3 -DNDEBUG -isystem /usr/local/bin/android-ndk/platforms/android-15/arch-arm/usr/include -isystem /usr/local/bin/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -isystem /usr/local/bin/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -isystem /usr/local/bin/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -I/usr/local/bin/android-ndk/sources/android/cpufeatures -I/usr/local/bin/android-ndk/sources/android/native_app_glue -ICore/Artifacts/Android -IApplications/Survey/Source -ICore/UI/. -ICore/UI/Source -ICore/ThirdParty/PowerVR/sdk/Include -ICore/ThirdParty/PowerVR/tools/include -ICore/ThirdParty/PowerVR/tools/include/OGLES2 -ICore/ThirdParty/boost/include -ICore/ThirdParty/openssl/include -ICore/ThirdParty/sqlite/include -ICore/WebServices/Source    -std=gnu++14 -MMD -MT Applications/Survey/CMakeFiles/Survey.dir/Source/View/RadioGroup.cpp.o -MF Applications/Survey/CMakeFiles/Survey.dir/Source/View/RadioGroup.cpp.o.d -o Applications/Survey/CMakeFiles/Survey.dir/Source/View/RadioGroup.cpp.o -c Applications/Survey/Source/View/RadioGroup.cpp

Note that I specify `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` when I generate.

The `-g` option is not present in the command line invocation, however the final binary is 19MB:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 bamboo bamboo 19173588 Jul 15 10:30 libzApp.so*
```

I ran `size` on it to determine what was making it so huge, but I got this:

```
$ size libzApp.so
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
7097019  201268   53488 7351775  702ddf libzApp.so
```

That only accounts for 7mb of data. So I ran this:

```
$ objdump --debugging libzApp.so | head -25

libzApp.so:     file format elf32-little

Contents of the .debug_abbrev section:

  Number TAG (0x0)
   1      DW_TAG_compile_unit    [has children]
    DW_AT_producer     DW_FORM_strp
    DW_AT_language     DW_FORM_data1
    DW_AT_name         DW_FORM_strp
    DW_AT_comp_dir     DW_FORM_strp
    DW_AT_low_pc       DW_FORM_addr
    DW_AT_entry_pc     DW_FORM_addr
    DW_AT_ranges       DW_FORM_data4
    DW_AT_stmt_list    DW_FORM_data4
    DW_AT value: 0     DW_FORM value: 0
   2      DW_TAG_typedef    [no children]
    DW_AT_name         DW_FORM_strp
    DW_AT_decl_file    DW_FORM_data1
    DW_AT_decl_line    DW_FORM_data1
    DW_AT_type         DW_FORM_ref4
    DW_AT value: 0     DW_FORM value: 0
   3      DW_TAG_base_type    [no children]
    DW_AT_byte_size    DW_FORM_data1
    DW_AT_encoding     DW_FORM_data1
```

I think this pretty much confirms that it has debug symbols. Can anyone help me understand why the .so is so large? Assuming it's because of debug symbols, what about the command line invocation would cause this?

### EDIT

As suggested in the comments section, running `strip` on the SO file definitely brings its size down to expected value (basically what we see from the result of the `size` command). However, why would debug symbols be built into the shared object when I specifically told GCC to not build debug symbols? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you confirm the size still same after`strip` ?

Comment: Yes, strip brings it down to an expected size: `$ ll libzApp.so` -- `-rwxrwxr-x 1 bamboo bamboo 7301876 Jul 15 11:18 libzApp.so*`

Comment: So is this solves your problem? Can you also try to remove ` -DNDEBUG` ?

Comment: Why do I need to `strip` the symbols? If I didn't tell gcc to build debug symbols, why do they exist in the first place? I'll try removing the NDEBUG and let you know how it goes, but I think we may have preprocessor conditionals that depend on this being set.

Comment: Actually I can't remove NDEBUG, that's defined in the android toolchain file I pulled from here: https://github.com/taka-no-me/android-cmake

Comment: For example, Qt always strip the symbols in release mode before deployment.

Comment: Also, try to pass `-s` parameter to the compiler.

Comment: I added a post build event to run the `strip` command, I didn't try the `-s` parameter but I think it would have worked as well, based on the docs I read. Feel free to provide a more detailed answer and I will mark it for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest you to use `strip` to remove the debugging information, eg:

```
strip libzApp.so
```

That is not so bad to do that because, for example, Qt's build system `qmake` always do that in it's `install` target of resulting Makefile.

By default, compiler always add a relocation information and symbol table into the binary. It also adds a lot of other information which may be stripped out (see link on answer below).

You may also use `-s` parameter to the compiler:

```
g++ -s ...
```

According to the docs:

> -s:
>
> ```
> Remove all symbol table and relocation information from the executable.
> ```

This flag should work exactly as `strip`. Here is also [some similiar answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15314861/1750757).