# Make C++ class partially constexpr and save RAM

Tags: c++, c++11

I have written code for a controller that has buttons and lamps. It is based on Arduino/ATmega2560. RAM is very limited. Changing to another device is no option.

Each button and lamp is modelled as a C++ class instance. They are derived from an abstract class `Thing`, which contains a pointer `mpTarget` that indicates connections between `Thing`s. The targets are initially assigned at runtime and do not change during runtime.

I need to save memory. As I have ~600 `Thing`s, it would help me alot if all those `mpTarget`s were stored in ROM (and not in RAM), because the targets are known at compile time.

So I played with `constexpr`. However, it seems to be impossible to make a class only partially `constexpr`. I cannot make the whole class `constexpr`, because there are also member variables that change during runtime (`mState` in the example below).

What would be a good way to achieve this behavior? constexpr? Templates? Anything?

### Clarifications

1. I know that `mpTarget` is currently initialized at runtime. But each target is *known* at compile time, that's why I'd like to find a good way to save RAM bytes of these pointers.
2. I don't really want to move away from object oriented design. I used an approach with simple, "plain old" datatypes before (which actually consumed less RAM). But as development of this code is still ongoing (classes and instances are added/deleted/modified), there is a high chance to miss necessary modifications, introducing hard-to-find bugs.
3. For this project, it would be more than enough to save the RAM storage only for `mpTarget`. Keeping the overhead of vtable pointers is fine. What I'm actually looking for is - as the title suggests - a way how we could implement a class whose members are *partially* `constexpr`. I also thought about using templates, but without success.

### Sample code

```
#include <iostream>

class Thing
{
  public:
  // only called in setup()
  void setTarget(Thing & pTarget)
  {
    mpTarget = & pTarget;
  }
  virtual void doSomething(int value) {};
  protected:
  // known at compile time - can we make this constexpr?
  Thing * mpTarget;
};

class Button : public Thing
{
  public:
  void setState(int newState)
  {
    mState = mState + newState;
    mpTarget->doSomething(mState);
  }
  
  private:
  // changes during runtime
  int mState;
};
class Lamp: public Thing
{
  public:
  virtual void doSomething(int value)
  {
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
  };
};


Button myButton;
Lamp myLamp;

int main()
{
  myButton.setTarget(myLamp);
  while (1)
  {
    myButton.setState(123);
  }
}
```

Comment: Whether a variable is stored in RAM or ROM, is not controllable by `constexpr` specifier fully. Hence it will make the premises weak for otherwise a good question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [g++ compiler flag to minimize binary size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314581/g-compiler-flag-to-minimize-binary-size) **EDIT** I now realize what you are trying to do is different. The context of the question I linked there may be interesting for you anyway, so I will leave it here.

Comment: How do you create/initialize your 600 `Thing`s?

Comment: @Mat - I initialize everything like in the example above. 600 instances in global scope without parameters. And then, at the beginning of runtime, call setTarget() for each instance.

Comment: @Mat - you are right - there is plenty of flash memory, I only use 20% of flash, but 80% of ATmega's 8k RAM.

Comment: Can't catch it! You simply can't set things in runtime and store in flash. "the targets are initially assigned at runtime" which means you can't store them as constant in flash. Please clarify your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use small state
2. Eliminate all virtual methods (and probably all base classes) to reduce class state.
3. Use Non-Type template parameters to move references from data (RAM) to code (ROM)

Use an `enum` based on a char for state when possible:

```
enum binary_enable_state : char {
    BINARY_ENABLE_ON,
    BINARY_ENABLE_OFF
};
```

Event listeners should just listen, and have no pointers or references or any real state.

```
class Lamp {
public:
  void doSomething(binary_enable_state value)
  {
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
  };
};
```

Event sources should uses non-type template parameter references to the listeners, thus avoiding pointers and state.

```
template<class Listener, Listener& mpTarget>
class Button {

  public:
  void setState(binary_enable_state newState)
  {
    mState = newState;
    mpTarget.doSomething(mState);
  }
  
  private:
  // changes during runtime
  binary_enable_state mState; //Do you actually need to store this?
};
```

This basically puts the graph in the code itself (ROM), rather than as data in RAM.

```
Lamp myLamp;
Button<decltype(myLamp), myLamp> myButton;

int main()
{
    myButton.setState(BINARY_ENABLE_ON);
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7171e4b9547ccbe1

Comment: Thank you, I accepted this answer because this tackles the main concern of my question (how to put the graph to ROM instead of RAM). The solution works great and saves me 4 RAM bytes for each pointer, which is more than enough for my application.

Comment: One more thing. Suppose my graph is a bit more complex, like:
`Lamp myLamp;
Relay<Lamp, myLamp> myRelay;
Button<Relay<Lamp, myLamp>, myRelay> myButton;`
 - I have to write nested template parameter lists. How to avoid that?

Comment: `using MyLampRelay = Relay<Lamp, myLamp>;` ?

Comment: Even better: `Button<decltype(myRelay), myRelay> myButton;`

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

## Redesign from ground up

ATmega2560 has just 8KB SRAM. This is extremely low compared to *normal*, desktop standards. 600 objects with 3 2-byte properties each would fill almost half of the available memory.

Programming on such a restrictive environment forces you to adapt your whole design from the start around the hardware limitations. Writing normal code and then trying to fit it to your hardware after the fact just doesn't cut it here. This is a good exception to the "first write readable code, then try it to optimize it".

## One idea: group by properties, not by objects

First you need to abandon virtual methods. That would add at least a vtable pointer per instance. At 600 instances it is a very heavy cost.

One ideea I have for a design here is to ditch the OOP completely. Or at least partially. Instead of properties grouped per instance, group all properties together in vectors.

This has a few big advantages:

- it saves space by abandoning the vtable
- because how properties are grouped it makes it possible to store the properties known at compile time in ROM
- it saves space by using the minimum number of bits necessary for each property

### Example

For the sake of example let's consider this scenario:

- we have 100 lamps, 200 buttons and 300 LEDs
- buttons and LEDs have a `target` property. Only lamps can be targets
- buttons have `state` property. There are 2 possible states (ON/OFF)
- LEDs have `color` property. There are 16 possible predefined colors

The following examples use literals to be explicit, but in code you should use constants (e.g. `NUM_BUTTONS` etc.)

#### `target` property

We have 500 (200 buttons + 300 LEDS) objects with `target` property. So we need a vector of size `500`. There are 100 targets. So the data type fits in a `int8_t`. So target looks like this:

```
constexpr int8t_t targets[500] = ...
```

In this vector the first 200 elements represent the targets of the buttons and the next 300 elements represent the targets of the LEDs. This vector will be stored in ROM.

To get the target of a thing we have:

```
int8_t button_target(int button) { return targets[button]; }
int8_t led_target(int led) { return targets[200 + led]; }
```

Alternatively use two vectors:

```
constexpr int8t_t button_targets[200] = ...
constexpr int8t_t led_targets[300] = ...
```

Populating this vector at compile time is a problem you need to solve. I don't know exactly how you are creating your objects now. You could hard code the values in the code or you could generate the code.

#### `state` property

We have 200 elements with state. Since there are 2 possible states we just need 1 bit per state. So we just need `200 / 8 = 25` bytes:

```
int8_t state[25] = {};
```

Getting and setting the state of a button is more complicated, it requires bitmask operations, but we have saved 175 bytes here (87.5% saved space on this data) and every byte matters.

```
bool button_get_state(int button)
{
    int8_t byte = state[button / 8];
    return byte & (1 << (button % 8));
}
```

#### `color` property

We have 300 elements with color. Since there are 16 colors we need 4 bits per color so we can encode 2 colors per byte:

```
int8_t color[150] = {};
```

Again getting and setting color requires bit fiddling.

## Conclusion

As you can see this design is by far not as pretty as OOP. And is it requires more complex code. But it has the big advantage that is saves you a lot of space, which is paramount on a device with just `8,192 bytes` of SRAM.

Comment: this "properties oriented design" is based on a cppcon talk. Unfortunately I don't remember how it was called and I can't find the talk.

Comment: ..no idea, it looks based on "Art of Programming" to me. WHich predates most of modern languages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, an approach like this was similar to that what I used previously. But because in the end there was too much of "fiddling" when editing code, that's why I started with an OOP approach. Note that the above is a bare minimum example; in fact there are ~20 classes, also having different relationships.