# Make compile-time register of global variables and save RAM

Tags: c++, c++17

I am on Arduino, using an ATmega 2560 with 8,192 bytes of RAM. RAM size is a big issue, but unfortunately, I can't change the platform. In the past, I had been successfully looking for ways to save memory in my use case ([Make C++ class partially constexpr and save RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65155791/make-c-class-partially-constexpr-and-save-ram) - I used the template-based approach of Mooing Duck, which saved me 2k of RAM).

However, I think we could save more RAM, consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

class A; // forward declaration
std::vector<A *> reg; // global variable for better readability here

class A
{
    public:
    A()
    {
        reg.push_back(this);
    }
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
    virtual void do_something()
    {
        printf("I am an instance of class B\n");
    }
    private:
    unsigned char some_state = 0; // not const
};

class C
{};

// known at compile time
B b1;
B b2;
C c1;
C c2;

int main()
{
    for (const auto inst: reg)
    {
        inst->do_something();
        // output:
        // I am an instance of class B
        // I am an instance of class B
    }
}
```

`b1`, `b2`, `c1` and `c2` are known at compile time, i.e. I use global variables. In total, I have got around 600 of these class instances, most of them feature a one-byte internal state. Some of the instances are derived from class A, some are not. In fact, there are around 20 classes which are like `B` (derived from `A`), and additional 10 classes which are like `C` (not derived from `A`).

The code above implements a way to call a method on each instance which is derived from A. This is done using a runtime register.

However, two things consume RAM:

1. The register itself (`std::vector<A *> reg;`), and
2. the virtual function pointers/vtables.

Like in the code above, I am looking for a way to call a function on each instance which is derived from `A`. But I want to save RAM. ROM size, however, is no issue at all.

Can we get rid of the runtime-register and put it to ROM in some elegant way?

And can we avoid virtual functions?

Thanks!

Comment: Why did you tag all the different C++ versions?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I didn't really think about that - I removed two of the tags.

Comment: Could you use `std::variant` for this?

Comment: Manually create something like `std::tuple all_As{std::ref(b1), std::ref(b2)}` (they no longer need to be `As` BTW).

Comment: @Galik That would be quite hard, I think. Actually, the variables form a directed graph, which is specified by templates and uses explicit variable naming. See the last part of this answer of my previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65587889

Comment: @Jarod42 I know this is possible, but I really want a way without manually enumerating (and introducing redundancy), because I have got so many instances and I definitely must ensure that there is no mistake.

Comment: With something like `struct AllAs { B b1; B b2; /*...*/ } allAs` with some reflection library to iterate over member, you avoid the redundancy (and still have nice syntax call contrary to `std::tuple`).

Comment: I wonder that you can use vector on AVR. Which library you are using? gcc did not provide STL at all for AVR or I am wrong?

Comment: @Jarod42 Your ```struct``` might be an idea. However, my variables form a directed graph (using templates), which implies that I have to sort these topologically, which further implies that I cannot group all ```A```s. But alternatively - could I store _all_ variables in a struct, find a good way to iterate over the members and use some template magic to identify all ```A```s?

Comment: @Klaus I took the STL library from here and added some C++17 templates manually: [link](https://github.com/smeshlink/Arduino-Plus/tree/master/hardware/tools/avr/lib/gcc/avr32/4.3.2/include/c%2B%2B)

Comment: Some libraries allows to iterate over members of class (they mostly rely on MACRO to define the class (or requires specific properties)). ([magic_get](https://github.com/boostorg/pfr), [BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_STRUCT](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/define_struct.html), ...)

Comment: And traits [`std::is_base_of<A, T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) might filter the `A`s.

Comment: Describe your arrangement of global variables in your favorite scripting language, write a script to generate C++ code from this definition. The script could e.g. produce a function `void CallDoSomethingOnEverything() { b1.DoSomething(); b2.DoSomething(); ... }`, listing the variables in the right order.

Comment: Oh my dear... I tried to dive into reflection (first time for me). But to achieve references within a struct, I'd have to declare all struct members `inline static`. But none of the reflection libraries I found provides means to iterate static struct members. I think I'm going to generate my code using some scripting language...

Comment: Instead of class with static members, use regular members instead, and make instance of that class global. (One (bigger) global instead of several globals).